# Can I turn off notifications to others when someone posts on my wall?

Tags: facebook

If someone posts on my wall on Facebook I don't want my other friends to be notified about this or have it shown on their feed. How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to precisely do it before hand. You can have a select few who can see what others post of your timeline

[image: Privacy]

Then choose custom

[image: Custom privacy]